# Insert error ORA - 00984

Tags: sql, oracle

I inserted a simple sql script like the one below and its give me an error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

insert into tableA values (id, colA, colB) 
values ( (select max(id)+1 from tableA), 'First Name', 'Second Name');

Table definition

id - number(15,0)
colA - varchar2(50)
colB - varchar2(50)
```

The following script works on another table with the same table definition but just varies on the number of columns. I am guessing the (select max(id)+1 from tableA) is causing the error, can anyone help? or have other solutions for this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you only want one `values` clause

```
insert into tableA (id, colA, colB) 
values ( (select max(id)+1 from tableA), 'First Name', 'Second Name');
```

That will solve your immediate problem.  That said, creating primary keys by doing the `max(id) + 1` from the table is a horrible practice-- it doesn't work in a multi-user environment and it doesn't scale.  You'd really, really want to create a sequence and use that sequence to generate your keys

```
create sequence tableA_seq
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  cache 20;

insert into tableA( id, colA, colB )
  values( tableA_seq.nextval, 'First Name', 'Second Name' );
```

Additionally, I'd strongly recommend that you not use `id` as the name of a column.  Something like `tableA_id` makes much more sense.  When you start writing queries that involve a number of different tables, it makes life far easier if `tableA_id` is the same name in the parent table and in all the child tables and when you don't have to work to figure out which `id` columns represent which concepts.

Comment: Thanks for helping Justin, actually i just renamed the table and column names so it would be much simpler. What does cache means?

Comment: @dimas - `cache` specifies the number of sequence values that are cached.  The default is 20.  If you're inserting a large number of rows, you might want to increase that for performance reasons.  If you want to reduce the number of sequence values that are "lost", you might want to decrease that and accept the (probably small) performance hit.

Comment: Ok, i thought its the number of integers i can insert in that column so in my case since table definition is number(15,0) then am limited to 15.

Comment: @dimas - `number(15,0)` means that the column can accept any integer up to 15 digits long (999,999,999,999,999)-- just under 1 quatrillion.